# jQuery/JS GET from one server, POST received file to another

Tags: jquery, ajax

We have recently purchased licenses for the use of some other people's web services in our code.  Basically, I need to be able to retrieve a file from one server then immediately POST that file to another server, and view the response text.

It seems easy enough since I've done these requests separately a lot.  I'm trying to test with getting a simple file from my own server and post it to this API.

Here's the current code I'm working with.

The API I'm posting through returns an error based on the fileModel parameter, so it would seem like I don't have a proper "data" variable (e.g. File).  I'm assuming that the data variable being returned by the GET call is not a true "File" type so the post is failing as a result.

I'm not sure how to properly create a "File" object that's returned from GET so that it posts correctly as a file.

```
$.get( "http://localhost/myfile.png", function( data ) {
    var sendData = {
        token : "mytokenhere",
        fileModel : data,
        title : "Cylinder1",
        description: "Cylinder1",
        private: true,
    };
    $.post( "https://api.url.com/", sendData)
        .done(function( data ) {
            alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
        })
        .fail( function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        });
});
```

Comment: Where's the question? Is that not working? If so, what's the stack trace or error? Is `data` in the outer `$.get` the correct value? Does it `GET` it correctly with with the binary file type?

Comment: I edited for clarity.  I think the issue is that the GET isn't returning the binary file type, just the file data?

Comment: Thanks - though two things. 1) I can't emphasize enough how much a question mark helps. 2) If the question is "How do I GET a binary file like an image with AJAX" and not the whole thing you should focus on that, or maybe that was already asked here ;)?

Comment: I attempted to ask it here, although I think I did it poorly, but yes, that is the question.

Comment: You should do this server side since when you attempt to get the actual file (not one from your server) same origin policy will come into play.

Comment: @VPel do you need to support IE<10 ?

Comment: Well I know the same-origin policies will be setup however I need them, but I still think you're right that I should divide these operations into server-side functions and work with them there.

Comment: Benjamin - I can live without that support for this module.

Answer (score 2):

You can't really get a binary response with $.get you'll have to use plain XMLHttpRequest

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
        //this.response is what you're looking for
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append('fileModel', this.response);
        data.append('description', "Cylinder1");
        data.append('private', true);
        data.append('title', "Cylinder1");
        data.append('token', "mytokenhere");
        $.ajax({
            url:'',
            type: 'post',
            data: data,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        })
        .done(function( data ) {
            alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
        })
        .fail( function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        });
    }
}
xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost/myfile.png');
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.send();
```

Comment: I ended up handling it a different way, some of which was server side, so it eliminated the need for this, although I think your answer is probably sound.