# Ajax Post dataURL using multipart/form-data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am am writing a program that pulls a dataURL from a canvas element and sends it server side to be converted back to a jpg and saved. What I need to do now, is to programmatically get this image from the server and post it using another ajax function as a multipart/form-data encoded form. There is some code that cannot be modified and it is expecting this type of post.

To be specific: how do I take an image from the server and put it into a POST of enctype="multipart/form-data" such that the code receiving the request sees it as if it were an post coming from a regular form. All of this using Jquery or JavaScript Ajax.

Extra info: The code being posted to is in ASP classic. I am using PHP to convert the DataURL.
PHP Code:

```
//Get the base-64 string from data
$data=$_POST['img_val'];

list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
$data = base64_decode($data);

file_put_contents('filename.png', $data);

$images_orig = imagecreatefrompng('filename.png');
$photoX = ImagesX($images_orig);
$photoY = ImagesY($images_orig);
$images_fin = ImageCreateTrueColor(650, 650);
ImageCopyResampled($images_fin, $images_orig, 0, 0, 0, 0, 650+1, 650+1, $photoX, $photoY);
imagejpeg($images_fin, NULL, 100);

ImageDestroy($images_orig);
ImageDestroy($images_fin);
```

The above code can be use to return either a binary Image File or to save the contents to disk and return an image URL. I'm not sure which will be more useful to my end goal.

Thanks to All.

Comment: What happens if you manually set `$data` to be a base64 string? Does the rest of the script perform as desired? Trying to determine what your problem is - if it's just getting the data from the post.

Comment: Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19067866/1353011 .It takes a file from the server and sends it as multipart/form-data.

Answer (score 3):

So for those who need a solution to something like this, the answer is a bit complicated. The above PHP code does properly convert the image from a dataURL to a png, and then resizes it as a jpg. The proper way to make a multipart/form-data Post from ajax goes like this:

```
var url = "example.php"
var image_as_blob = previousAjaxRequest(); //use xhr.responseType = "blob" and a GET request to grab server image 
var form = new FormData();
form.append('image_variable_name', image_as_blob, 'file_name.extension'); //the third argument seemed to make all the difference in server code seeing the file correctly.
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'post',
    data: form,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false, //required for multipart
    processData: false  //required for multipart
}).done(function( data ) {
    //do what you want with returned data
});
```

Comment: where is previousAjaxRequest()?